# How was Silver Surfer able to kill/banish Galactus in Fantastic Four 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-four-2

Galactus is supposed to be an ancient ultra-powerful being, while all Silver Surfer has is a tiny fraction of Galactus' powers. Galactus has the ability to grant more or completely take away the powers that he had granted to Silver Surfer.

In the movie, Galactus has traveled all the way to Earth and is beginning to feed on it when Silver Surfer rebels. What could Silver Surfer possibly do to not only stop Galactus but also banish (possibly kill?) him away from the Earth?

The only reason that I can think of is that it was required by the script but I wonder if there is some explanation somewhere that I missed.

Comment: I think that tracks to the original Silver Surfer story in the comics.  Maybe someone who followed the Fantastic Four in its original, non-movie form can fill us in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as I commented, this is necessary in the script because that is an integral part of the original Silver Surfer story in the Fantastic Four comics, from 1966.

In the comics, when the Silver Surfer rebelled, he collaborated with the Fantastic Four and a being known as Uatu who was one of the beings known as "the Watchers" who monitored the activity of species throughout the universe.

In the comics, Uatu helps Johnny Storm travel to Galactus' home world/base and retrieve a device called the Ultimate Nullifier, which, being from Galactus' home, is on the scale of that being in power, and is supposedly the only weapon that he fears.  Galactus then banishes the Silver Surfer to the Earth (via special field that traps him here) and goes back to the Surfer's homeworld to lay waste to it, since he reneged on his part of the deal.

Anyway, that's why the script requires that the Surfer rebel and Galactus be driven off.  Seems kind of lazy that they didn't just incorporate that into the movie.

Most of this information came from the Wikipedia pages for the Silver Sufer, Galactus, Uatu, and the Ultimate Nullifier.

Comment: Thanks for the nullifier information. The idea of Galactus punishing Surfer for the rebellion by destroying his planet and leaving him alive to experience the pain makes sense too. Killing Surfer outright might have been less of a punishment in Galactus' eyes.

Answer (score 3):

Galactus is motivated by a deep seated hunger and need to gather energy. He does not like to waste energy or effort. While the Surfer has only a fraction of the power cosmic, it's still sufficient enough to annoy Galactus away. He made the Earth no longer seem worthwhile to eat. Too much of an effort.

Like people shoeing away a bear from their pic a nic baskets. Sure the bear could maul them to death, but it would be by opening the bear up to a fight and further risks. It's easier to find another meal.

Which mythology states he does. He locks the Surfer to the Earth, and then eats the Surfers original home world.

Comment: Interesting argument! I agree with the bear example but not fully with how easier it'd be to find another meal given he has to appoint subordinates like Silver Surfer to find consumable planets. But yes, he probably already had a lock on Surfer's home planet, so that's an easy meal waiting right there.

Comment: @Achilles he doesn't have to, its just convenient for him.